# Replace the content in between using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
'[text], text, {text}, itextm'
```

I should end up with:

```
'[replaced], text, {replaced}, ireplacedm'
```

How can I do it with python re module?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you thought of and tried?

Comment: Have a look at `re.sub()`.

Comment: What *exactly* are the parameters of when things should be replaced? Any time the text you're looking for appears within two non-whitespace characters? Are you trying to replace all such text, or just specific strings? You need to give a lot more specificity if you want anyone to give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: s='[text], text, {text}, itextm'
In [2]: import re
In [3]: re.sub(r'([[{])[^\]}]*',r'\1replaced',s)
Out[3]: '[replaced], text, {replaced}, itextm'
```

**EDIT**

ah... I didn't notice the last part of your example, the `ireplacedm`!

now this should work for your example:

```
In [8]: re.sub(r'([^ ,])text([^ ,])',r'\1replaced\2',s)                                                                                                                     
Out[8]: '[replaced], text, {replaced}, ireplacedm'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect since it will not work properly if you have a setup like `[term}more]`, but it at least works for your example.

```
re.sub(r'([[{]).*?([\]}])', r'\1replaced\2', str)
```

Comment: I got the same idea as yours. take a look the last word in his output. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
import re

pattern = '(?<=(\[)|(\{)|([a-z])|.)text(?=(?(1)]|(?(2)}|(?(3)|[a-z]))))'
subject = '[text], text, {text}, itextm [text} {text] textus atext'
result = re.sub(pattern, 'replaced', subject)

print result
```

it tests if square or curly brackets are balanced or match the word when there is at least one letter at the beginning or at the end.

Result:

```
[replaced], text, {replaced}, ireplacedm [text} {text] replacedus areplaced
```